# Is it possible to connect Web App to TV over WiFi or some other method?

Tags: javascript, television

For my web application (React), I either need to connect the app to the TV over WiFi or some other technology, as opposed to manually opening up a browser and entering the URL, or to somehow direct the TV to open my website.

Is this possible currently? Is there a way to scan the WiFi to find all devices connected to it, and somehow push data over WiFi to the TV to open a specific website?

I've found ConnectSDK (https://connectsdk.com/) which seems to make this possible but only for Android/iOS devices.

Comment: Google "javascript chromecast" Chromecast is the general technology used to cast from a PC/phone/tablet to a TV.

Comment: There is a Presentation API in the works for exactly this purpose. Currently it is experimental.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API